# Updating view properties SharePoint 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-webservice

I am trying to create a view programatically using another view as a template.  I have gotten everything working (creating the view and then using updateView).  The only snag is I am trying to set `TabularView=FALSE` but the change is not taking.  Here is the code I have so far

```
System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
System.Xml.XmlNode viewProperties = doc.CreateNode(System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Element,"View","");
System.Xml.XmlAttribute attr = doc.CreateAttribute("TabularView");
attr.Value = "FALSE";
viewProperties.Attributes.SetNamedItem(attr);
System.Xml.XmlNode resNode = view.UpdateView(listname, name, viewProperties, query, viewFields, null, null, rowLimit);
```

As usual the MSDN page on the [updateView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/views.views.updateview(v=office.12).aspx) does not provide any information on the viewProperties parameter

Please note that I can only use WebServices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cross posted this question on MSDN and got the following answer:

> Hi Kevin,   According to your description, my understanding is that
>   you want to set view property using web service.   In the UpadateView
>   method, the viewProperties has no TabularView attribute, so it will
>   not work.   In the viewPropeties tag, you can set the attribute such
>   as as Editor, Hidden, ReadOnly, and Title.   Here is a similiar thread
>   for your reference:
>   https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/5540/update-list-view-title-using-views-asmx-web-service
>   Best Regards
>
> ---
>
> Zhengyu Guo  TechNet Community Support